# Mapping collisions in vim

Tags: vim, mapping

Is there a way to find out that my new mapping won't collide with some keyboard shortcut already set in vim? For example I will want to map `gg` to something because I don't know that vim uses it to go to the beginning of the file. How to get know that this mapping is already used for another purpose?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to run `:help gg` or `:help _` or `:help ctrl-y` to see if the mapping I'm thinking of over-writing is useful to me or not.

The `^D` completion command can be helpful, try this:

```
:help ctrl^D
```

That's typing `ctrl` with four letters, then hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get completion list. It shows help topics matching `ctrl`.

Typically, `\` or `,` or `_` characters are used as 'leader' characters, and you place all your mappings behind it. Not as convenient, but when everything is already taken...

Answer (score 3):

If you enter the following into command mode:

```
 :map gg<cr>
```

Vim will tell you what that is currently mapped to.

If you do:

```
 :map g
```

Vim will tell you all mappings that begin with g

Comment: `:map gg<cr>` = `No mapping found`

Comment: As the other answer suggests you can also :h gg to check it's not a default binding

Comment: You can also use `:verbose map gg<CR>` to find in which file the mapping is defined if it exists. It is useful when you have plenty of plugins installed.

Answer (score 1):

For built-in commands and mappings `:help index` lists them all. `:map` will only list user-defined mappings.